# how does python2.7 deal with unicode? I am more and more confused

Tags: python, unicode

in linux, I opened terminal and input **python2.7** and then input the codes as follows:

```
>>> s = u'\u0561'
>>> print s
ա
>>> len(s)
1
```

the length of u'\u0561' is only 1? Why?I learned that every non-alphabet character's length is 2~4 byte in unicode, why does it use only 1 byte? and i test other unicode characters, i found that almost all the unicode character's length is 1, why?

Comment: Just to confuse you, try this on a narrow build (i.e. `sys.maxuincode == 0xffff`): `len(u'\U00010000')`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `len` function doesn't count the number of bytes - it count the number of items in any sequence (in this case, the number of characters in the string).

Answer (score 1):

> the length of u'\u0561' is only 1? Why?

Because ա is one character.

In other words, for the same reason that the `len()` of `['hi mom this is an incredibly long string']` is 1: because `'hi mom this is an incredibly long string'` is one list item.

Answer (score 0):

It's giving you the length in characters, not bytes.

```
\u0561
```

This is one character, so the length is one.